# Visual studio fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll. When installing pandas

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pandas

I am trying to pip install pandas and i keep receiving this error:

```
      fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll.
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
      14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 4
```

I tired uninstalling and repair but it still prompt me this error. Is there any ways i can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling that you must be using an old version of PIP.

It may sound simple but please try this code.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Niche! You saved me!

Comment: glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

If running `pip install --upgrade pip` doesn't fix the issue (like in my case).

Your first step would be to check either Visual Studio or the standalone build libraries (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/) are installed to get the build libraries

In my case this was a cloud machine where I could not install these libraries -_-

so just installing from a wheel file 
from somewhere like https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ got around the .dll issue

```
python -m pip install your-downloaded-file-goes-here.whl
```

if you can't find a wheel file here you could build the whl file yourself from source on a machine where you *can* install build libraries

```
git clone https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
```

change into the directory with setup.py

```
cd pandas
```

make sure  the python you are using to build is the the exact same python version as the machine you are installing on

```
python setup.py bd_dist
```

then you will find the `.whl` file in `/dist` which I copied to remote machine

if above doesn't work may need to install build tools if you haven't already

```
python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
```

looking at your case you may need to install these additional packages to compile pandas from source

```
python -m pip install cython numpy
```

see https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#generating-distribution-archives